# unable to get message from external web application to addon

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I have created a chrome extension, and I want to make a 2-way communication between my external web application.

To start I want to send a message from my external HTML page to the addon, so I dig on the internet and found this [guide](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/#host-page-communication), And I have made some adjustments because it was not completely worked.

This is my V3 manifest:

```
 {
  "name": "Default Name",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "action": {
    "default_title": "Default Title"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "windows",
    "activeTab",
    "tabs",
    "identity"
  ],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "externally_connectable": {
    "ids": [
      "*"
    ],
    "matches": [
      "http://localhost/*",
      "http://localhost:3000/*",
      "https://localhost/*",
      "https://localhost:3000/*",
      "http://localhost:63342/*"
    ]
  },
  "host_permissions": [
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*",
    "*://*/*"
  ]
}
```

my `background.js`:

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener( () => {
    console.log("just installed")
});

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(async (data, sender, sendResponse) => {
    console.log("date", data)
    console.log("sender", sender)
    console.log("sendResponse", sendResponse)
});
```

And this is my External webpage:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        const clickMe = () => {
            console.log("button has been clicked");
            window.postMessage(
                {type : "FROM_PAGE", text : "Hello from the webpage!"}, "*");
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="clickMe()">click me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

While installing the addon, I am receiving the message from the `onInstalled` listener so it means the code is working, but when I am clicking on the `button` on the HTML page I am not receiving anything on the add-on console.

In addition, how can I send a response back to the external web page application from the addon?

Comment: It was the wrong guide. Use the correct one [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external-webpage).

Comment: @wOxxOm, but how can I send the message from the external web application?
I can see only examples with `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` but `chrome` is undefined

Comment: The article describes everything you need, so `chrome` will be defined once you do it. Don't forget to reload the extension and the tab after editing.

Comment: @wOxxOm, its look like a missing configuration in the IDE, I have fixed it, and managed to send message to external web application. can you please tell or point me to a way that i can have 2-communication? like the web app and addon can speak together?

Comment: Use sendResponse + callback as shown at the beginning of the same article.